# Loop Delay Timeout Issue

Tags: javascript, loops, delay

I'm working on a HTML5 game, and currently trying to make a weapon that fires 3 projectiles a few seconds after each other. So basically, a 3 burst assault rifle.

I first did:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   player.bullets.push(bulletInstance);
}
player.shotBullet = true;
```

which worked, but of course, the projectiles where release at the same time, meaning there was no delay between each shot. So I tried to introduce a setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout(function (){
    i++;
    if(i < 3){
        var b = new Rectangle( player.x + (player.width / 2) - 4, player.y + (player.height / 2) - 4, 8, 8);

        player.bullets.push(bulletInstance);
    }
}, 1000)
player.shotBullet = true;
```

This doesn't do the trick either. Could someone point out my problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way would be like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){

   window.setTimeout( function(){ player.bullets.push(bulletInstance); }, i * 1000 );

}
```

This will init 3 functions 1s apart, which each firing a bullet according to your logic.

You probably will have to create separate instances of `bulletInstance`.

If there are much more than 3 actions to be done, I'd suggest to switch to `setInterval()` instead. But in such low areas, `setTimeout()` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Being more specific about what is not wouking would help. In your case, the problem is that setTimeout runs only once. You should either create a new settimeout call inside the handler or use setInterval instead (just remember to clearInterval when you are done so it stops)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) from jQuery.